# Send response to ipcRenderer from ipcMain

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I am currently building an electron app where i need to store something in the app. For that I am using electron-store which works perfectly. Now I need to initialize an ipcMain.on("get-license-key"). Them I am calling ipcRenderer.send("get-license-key", "") now I want the ipcMain.on("get-license-key") to return the license key from electron-store so I can use it like this:

```
const licenseKey = ipcRenderer.send("get-license-key", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is [`invoke`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args)/[`handle`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener), and not [`send`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-args)/[`on`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainonchannel-listener).

**renderer.js**

```
const licenseKey = await ipcRenderer.invoke("get-license-key");
```

**main.js**

```
ipcMain.handle("get-license-key", () => "the-licence-key");
```